# Runtime Classpath in WAS

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, ibm-rad

In RAD, when we create a project, and go Properties, there is an option called Java EE Module Dependencies. When we add some jars here, does it add it to the runtime path?
What is this option for?
Also, when WAS is running and multiple EARs are deployed, how will WAS pickup the runtime classpath for each EAR? Will it be the same for all EARs?
Will it just take the Build path entries for each EAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the runtime class paths are a combination of the following.

1. the class path & jar files configured as part of the shared libraries (can be set from the environment menu item)
2. the applications class path (ie., <>/.../lib)
3. any additional configuration (for classpath) made while configuring the java instance for websphere.

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime class path and Build path are completely different (and have no relationship whatsoever).

The Java EE specs states what constitutes the runtime class path and using App Server specific entities like Shared Library adds additional class paths to the runtime servers.

WAS allows you to have a class loader for each Enterprise Application or have a single classloader for all EARs that are hosted on a server.

The former is the default and the preferred option.

Typically when you add dependencies you can specify which one of these should be part of the runtime class path.